# How to delete entire ids with event in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `df` looks like

```
ID  Drugs       Event
123 Insulin     1
123 Bigunaides  2
123 SGLT2       3
234 Insulin     1
234 SGLT2       3
345 Bigunaides  2
345 SGLT2       3
456 SGLT2       3
567 DPP4        4
```

I want delete the entire ids if there is Event == 1

Expected output

```
ID  Drugs      Event
345 Bigunaides  2
345 SGLT2       3
456 SGLT2       3
567 DPP4        4
```

Answer (score -1):

We can do a group by `filter`.  Grouped by 'ID', `filter` all groups where the 'Event' doesn't have 1

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter( all(Event != 1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Drugs      Event
#  <int> <chr>      <int>
#1   345 Bigunaides     2
#2   345 SGLT2          3
#3   456 SGLT2          3
#4   567 DPP4           4
```

---

Or another option is

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(!1 %in% Event)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Drugs      Event
#  <int> <chr>      <int>
#1   345 Bigunaides     2
#2   345 SGLT2          3
#3   456 SGLT2          3
#4   567 DPP4           4
```

NOTE: Both solutions work

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 234L, 234L, 345L, 345L, 
456L, 567L), Drugs = c("Insulin", "Bigunaides", "SGLT2", "Insulin", 
"SGLT2", "Bigunaides", "SGLT2", "SGLT2", "DPP4"), Event = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```